# OpenAPI pathvariables are null when GET-ing the endpoint

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, openapi

I'm trying to implement a Rest endpoint using swagger and yaml files. Below you can see the generated interface:

```
public interface MyInterface {

    @ApiOperation(value = "Get Customers", nickname = "getCustomers", notes = "", response = Customers.class, tags = {
                "Customers })
                @ApiResponses(value = {
                    @ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "A Customers object.", response = Customers.class),
                    @ApiResponse(code = 400, message = "Bad request (parameter error)", response = Error.class),
                    @ApiResponse(code = 403, message = "Forbidden access (restricted to admins and the authenticated user only)", response = Error.class),
                    @ApiResponse(code = 404, message = "Customers referred not found", response = Error.class),
                    @ApiResponse(code = 500, message = "unexpected error", response = Error.class)
                })
                @RequestMapping(value = "/api/{supplierId}/customer/{quoteId}/{collectionId}",
                    produces = {
                        "application/json"
                    },
                    method = RequestMethod.GET)
                ResponseEntity < Customers > getCustomers(
                    @ApiParam(value = "The ID of the supplier (not supplier code)", required = true) @PathVariable("supplierId") Integer supplierId,
                    @ApiParam(value = "The ID of quote object", required = true) @PathVariable("quoteId") Integer quoteId,
                    @ApiParam(value = "The ID of collection within the quote", required = true) @PathVariable("collectionId") Integer collectionId,
                    @ApiParam(value = "The ID of the language", required = true, defaultValue = "en") @PathVariable("language") String language,
                    @NotNull @ApiParam(value = "The ID of the customer", required = true) @Valid @RequestParam(value = "customerId", required = true) String customerId);

}

@RestController
public MyImplementation implements MyInterface {

    @Override
    public ResponseEntity < Customers > getCustomers(Integer supplierId, Integer quoteId, Integer collectionId, String language, String customerId) {
        return new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.NOT_IMPLEMENTED);
    }
}
```

When I send a Get request to my endpoint like that:

```
localhost:8080/api/212/customer/300/222?customerId=940
```

all the `@PathVariable`s are null (`supplierId`, `collectionId`, ...). Only the `@RequestParam` `customerId` is populated. What could be the problem here?

[image]

**Edit 1:** Here's the yaml-file:

```
openapi: "3.0.0"
info:
  version: 1.0.0
  title: Customer Actions
  description: API related to RfQ actions
servers:
  - url: http://localhost:8080/MyDomain
    description: Local development
paths: 
  /api/{supplierId}/rfq/{quoteId}/{collectionId}:
    get:
      summary: Get Customers
      operationId: getCustomers
      tags:
        - Suppliers
      parameters:
        - name: supplierId
          in: path
          required: true
          description: The ID of the supplier (not supplier code)
          schema:
            type: integer
        - name: quoteId
          in: path
          required: true
          description: The ID of quote object
          schema:
            type: integer
        - name: collectionId
          in: path
          required: true
          description: The ID of collection within the quote
          schema:
            type: integer
        - name: language
          in: query
          required: true
          description: The ID of the language
          schema:
            type: string
            default: en
        - name: customerId
          in: query
          required: true
          description: The ID of the customer
          schema:
            type: string
      responses:
        200:
          description: A Customers object.
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                type: Customers
        400:
          $ref: "#/components/responses/400"
        403:
          $ref: "#/components/responses/403"
        404:
          $ref: "#/components/responses/404"
        500:
          $ref: "#/components/responses/500"
```

**Edit 2:** I have found a solution to my problem. What I did was I added the method signature (variables) annotation from the interface to the implementation method. Now my values are populated. However, as I understand it based on [this link](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-interface-driven-controllers), this information should be automatically available at the implementation.

```
    @Override        
    public ResponseEntity<FileDetails> getQuoteRateItems(
            @PathVariable("supplierId") String supplierId,
            @PathVariable("quoteId") String quoteId,
            @PathVariable("collectionId") String collectionId,
            @RequestParam(value = "customerId", required = true) String customerId,
            @RequestParam(value = "language", required = false, defaultValue="en") String language) {
        return new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.NOT_IMPLEMENTED);
```

Is that the normal procedure that I have to annotate this stuff twice? Because it violates the DRY principle.

Comment: does it work when you remove @ApiParam from getCustomers interface?

Comment: Could you add the `.yaml` file and OpenApi version?

Comment: Have added the .yaml file.

Comment: @Szprota21: I tried that but same behaviour.

Comment: So first of all you should remove that swagger code and tag from here because It's not relevant. Also I'm pretty sure that in implementation you should use @RestController annotation before class declaration. Anyway that whole post is missleading

Comment: I found a solution to my problem (see initial post) but I'm not happy with it because it violates the DRY principle.